# Error: THREE is not defined inside FBXLoader

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, node-modules, fbx

I'm using the module version of three.js because I need to run imports from a client-side js file structure.

THREE itself works fine. But now I'm having the issue that I cannot use it in FBXLoader:

This is the import statement on my client-side rendering file:

```
import * as THREE from '/build/three.module.js';
import * as FBXLoader from '/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js';
```

This does not throw any errors.

Server-side, I'm using express to allow access to modules on client-side:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/build/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/build')));
app.use('/js/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/examples/js')));
```

So far so good.

When I try to run, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js:22
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js:3817
```

Any ideas what the problem is? There error is not in my code, this is something inside FBXLoader.js.

Answer (score 1):

A file's imports are scoped to that file. It may be that FBXLoader.js isn't importing THREE and that's why it's undefined. Include in FBXLoader.js:

```js
import * as THREE from '/build/three.module.js';
```

Comment: This solved the problem posted above, but caused a new problem:
It now says that

```THREE.FBXLoader = FBXLoader;```

FBXLoader at the bottom of the FBXLoader lib is read-only.

Comment: it did not cause a new problem, the problem was there your code failed before it got to the next error. not all modules are imported the same way https://sbcode.net/threejs/loaders-fbx/  use  ```import { FBXLoader } from '/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js';``` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try by using js modules, so instead of importing from "js" try from "jsm".

```
app.use('/js/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/examples/jsm')));
```